# How to send input/select fields within a form without refreshing page (PHP/AJAX/JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have few field within a form to dynamically add data to database. I send data from couple fields to php using ajax and receive correct response. But when i click button with attached click handler to submit required fields whole form being reloaded i dont know why. Could somebody please help me out. Anyway thanks in advance ;)

```
  $("#button").click(
    function(){
        var somedata1= $(".someinput").val();
        var somedata2= $(".someselect").val();
        ajax_post('http://someurlhere', 
        'some1='+somedata1+'&some2='+somedata2+'&csrf_token='+csrf_token, handle_submit, handle_error);
    }
);
```

Comment: Look for `event.preventDefault()` function.

Comment: @U-ways CORS?..

Comment: with event.preventDefault() click handler doesnt submit required fields, ajax submitting empty request. I have read messages related to the thread very attentively but havent found anything working enought. Probably i put it in wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the default action that submitting a form does (reloading the page).

```
$("#button").click(
  function(e){
    // this prevents the default action from the submit action
    e.preventDefault();
    var somedata1= $(".someinput").val();
    var somedata2= $(".someselect").val();
    ajax_post('http://someurlhere', 
    'some1='+somedata1+'&some2='+somedata2+'&csrf_token='+csrf_token, handle_submit, handle_error);
  }
);
```